# I am trying to make a circle at a random point

Tags: python

```
cir = Circle(rand,8)
```

I need to make a circle that appears at a random spot inside a window. I'm not sure how to do this, do I do something like above or do I do:

```
 circle.x=random.random()
 circle.y=random.random()
```

Comment: Which window library are you using? Do you need suggestions on a window library as well?

Comment: from random import randint, choice

Answer (score 0):

import `randint` from the `random` library, then do the following:

```
from random import randint

circle.radius = 10
circle.x = random.randint(0, DISPLAY_WIDTH - circle.radius) #Put display width in for variable
circle.y = random.randint(0, DISPLAY_HEIGHT - circle.radius) #Put display height in for variable
```

Comment: should be x = (r, w-r) and y = (r, h-r)